# Why isn't checkbox B enabled when I check checkbox A?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two checkboxes, A and B. They should behave according to the following rules:

1. A should always be enabled.
2. B should only be enabled when A is checked
3. If A and B is checked, and A is later un-checked, B should be un-checked and disabled automatically.

I have this code so far:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="A" />A
<input type="checkbox" id="B" />B
```

jQuery

```
$('#A').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $('#B').attr('disabled', false)
    } else {
        $('#B')
            .attr('disabled', true)
            .attr('checked', false);
    }
}).change();
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/u0vw5q92/3/).

Comment: Because checking the input makes the `checked` **property** be true.  It does not add an **attribute** of `checked` to the element.  You need to use `prop()`, not `attr()` for the checked test

Comment: @Taplar Yes! Thank you! If you write it up as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native `this.checked` for a checkbox.  Also, since you're wanting to test the state of an element in the DOM, you can use `prop()` to get and change the properties in the DOM.

```js
$('#A').change(function () {
  var $B = $('#B');
  
  $B.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  
  if (!this.checked) $B.prop('checked', false);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="A" />A
<input type="checkbox" id="B" />B
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
$('#A').on('change', function(e){
 if(e.target.checked){
    $('#B').prop('disabled', false);
  } else{
   $('#B').prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    The if statement doesn't trigger when checking checkbox A. B just stays disabled.
</p>
<p>
    <input checked id="A" type="checkbox" />A
</p>

<p>
    <input id="B" type="checkbox" />B
</p>
```

The preferred way to add event handlers in jQuery is `.on()`

Also, you had a duplicate `.change()`.

JS Fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jv7e4zu9/)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it jQuery you can use `is()` to check state.

```js
$('#A').change(function() {
  $("#B")
  .prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"))
  .prop("checked",($(this).is(":checked") && $("#B").is(":checked")));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="A" />A
<input type="checkbox" id="B" disabled />B
```